# MYSQL advance searching - order by with LIKE operator

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-like

```
SELECT title
FROM team
WHERE
title LIKE '%la fontaine e%' OR 
MATCH(title, title_fr, summary, seo_keyword, seo_description) AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +e) (la fontaine e)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY title LIKE '%la%' OR title LIKE '%fontaine%' OR title LIKE '%e%' ASC;
```

which results

[image]

and I want to popup result such that following rows come first

```
La fontaine à eau Edelvia Home 11L
La fontaine à eau Edelvia Home 11L livrée à domicile
```

and the result will filter & sort based on typing the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean expression will be `1` if the `title`-column does not include any of your search terms, and `0` if not. So you will have to change `asc` to `desc` to order `1` before `0`.

But `like` will not consider word boundaries, so `LIKE '%e%'` is true for any value that contains an `e` *anywhere* (e.g. `home`). That means that even if you *do* change `asc` to `desc`, you will, at least for your sample data, still get an arbitrary order, as every row does actually contain an `e` somewhere, and so your boolean expression will be true for all results.

You may want to consider e.g. `order by (title LIKE '%la%') + (title LIKE '%fontaine%') + (title LIKE '%e%') desc` or something similar, so more (partial) keyword matches result in a better position. Otherwise, adding more keywords can make your order worse: a search for `"fontaine"` orders as expected, a search for `"fontaine e"` has again no order at all.

If you actually want to respect word boundaries, so if you basically want to do a fulltext search that prioritizes the `title` column for ordering, you may want use the actual relevance score to order your results. It should (probably) give you a better order than just "it contains any of the search terms". Try e.g.

```
order by MATCH(title) 
AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +e) (la fontaine e)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

or

```
order by MATCH(title) 
AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +e) (la fontaine e)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC,
MATCH(title, title_fr, summary, seo_keyword, seo_description) 
AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +e) (la fontaine e)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

or

```
order by MATCH(title) 
AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +e) (la fontaine e)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 5 
+ MATCH(title, title_fr, summary, seo_keyword, seo_description) 
AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +e) (la fontaine e)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

This will require you to add a seperate fulltext index on `title`.

You should also be aware about the limitations and options of a fulltext search. For example, the index will by default not include words shorter than [3 (for InnoDB)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) or [4 (for MyISAM)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len), so `e` or `la` would not be included in the index and cannot be found. Additionally, some common words like `the` are excluded via a [stopword list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) (the default content of that stopword list will significantly differ for MyISAM and InnoDB). Also, a fulltext index will get slower the more result it will find. So a search for a single rare word is very fast, while a search for a combination of several key words that will return a large portion of your data can (depending on the size of your table) become painfully slow.

A side note: `title LIKE '%la fontaine e%'` is not the same as finding separate words - it will find e.g. `'Isabella Fontaine est'` too. And your `match against`-part will also include result already, as it contains the word `Fontaine`. Although that only holds if you search for more than 2 words, otherwise, `title LIKE '%la fontaine%'` will find `'Isabella Fontainebleau'`, which does not contain the words `la` or `fontaine`. I am not sure if that is the behaviour you want or expect.

Comment: Now query become 
SELECT title
FROM team
WHERE 
MATCH(title, title_fr, meta_tags, summary, seo_keyword, seo_description) AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +eau) (la fontaine eau)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR title LIKE '%la fontaine eau%' 
ORDER BY MATCH(title) AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +eau) (la fontaine eau)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC;

but first row is 
- Fontaine à eau pour chien et chat Fresh & Clear Dogit Design

and desire rows on from second to third
- La fontaine à eau pour chats et chiens Vega
- La fontaine à eau Edelvia Home 11L
- La fontaine à eau Edelvia Home 11L livrée à domicile

Comment: If I understand your follow-up correctly: if you search for "la fontaine eau", the word "la" (and maybe, if you use MyISAM, the word "eau") is (by default) ignored, as it is shorter than 3 or 4 (I mentioned that in the limitations-part, you may have missed that; it also includes links to the config settings). If you want it to have any effect on the fulltext score, you have to change the configuration option *and* then rebuild your index. If that was not your problem, you have to clarify it more, since I didn't understand it then.

Answer (score 0):

I have already defined **fulltext** index for those columns. 
Now query become

```
SELECT title
FROM team
WHERE 
MATCH(title, title_fr, meta_tags, summary, seo_keyword, seo_description) AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +eau) (la fontaine eau)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR title LIKE '%la fontaine eau%' 
ORDER BY MATCH(title) AGAINST('(+la +fontaine +eau) (la fontaine eau)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC;
```

but first row is

```
- Fontaine à eau pour chien et chat Fresh & Clear Dogit Design
```

and desire rows on from second to onward

```
- La fontaine à eau pour chats et chiens Vega
- La fontaine à eau Edelvia Home 11L
- La fontaine à eau Edelvia Home 11L livrée à domicile
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand your follow-up correctly: if you search for "la fontaine eau", the word "la" (and maybe, if you use MyISAM, the word "eau") is (by default) ignored, as it is shorter than 3 or 4 (I mentioned that in the limitations-part, you may have missed that; it also includes links to the config settings). If you want it to have any effect on the fulltext score, you have to change the configuration option and then rebuild your index. If that was not your problem, you have to clarify it more, since I didn't understand it then.