# How to Sort Results Order by Best Match using LIKE in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am working with a MySQL query which I want to sort by best match. But it's not sorting results as needed.

My Data

```
Table Name : my_table
Datas :
+----+----------------------------------+
| id |               name               |
+----+----------------------------------+
| 01 | Sayed Mahbubul Alom              |
+----+----------------------------------+
| 02 | Syed Masud Alom                  |
+----+----------------------------------+
| 03 | Shofiul Alom                     |
+----+----------------------------------+
| 04 | Lieutenant Colonel Mohammod Alom |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

My search keyword

```php
$keyword = 'colonel alom';
```

Separated Keyword

```php
$single_keyword = explode(" ", $keyword);
print_r($single_keyword);
array
(
    0 => 'colonel',
    1 => 'alom'
)
```

My SQL Query

```php
$query = SELECT name FROM my_table
WHERE
    name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR";
    foreach ($single_keyword as $single) {
        $query = $query." name LIKE '%$single%' OR";
    }
    $query = substr($query,0,-3); // To remove the last OR
$query = $query." ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN name LIKE '$keyword' THEN 1";
    if (count($single_keyword ) > 1) {
        $keyword_count = count($single_keyword);
        $query = $query." WHEN"; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < $keyword_count; $i++) {
            $query = $query." name LIKE '$single_keyword[$i]' AND";
        }
        $query = substr($query,0,-3); // To remove the last AND
        $query = $query." THEN 2 ELSE 3";
    } else {
        $query = $query." ELSE 2";
    }
$query = $query." END";
```

My query generating this SQL

```sql
SELECT name FROM my_table
WHERE
    name LIKE '%colonel alom%' OR
    name LIKE '%colonel%' OR
    name LIKE '%alom%'
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN name LIKE 'colonel alom' THEN 1
    WHEN name LIKE 'colonel' AND name LIKE 'alom' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END
```

The result I am getting is

```
+-------+----+----------------------------------+
| index | id |               name               |
+-------+----+----------------------------------+
|   0   | 02 | Syed Masud Alom                  |
+-------+----+----------------------------------+
|   1   | 01 | Sayed Mahbubul Alom              |
+-------+----+----------------------------------+
|   2   | 03 | Shofiul Alom                     |
+-------+----+----------------------------------+
|   3   | 04 | Lieutenant Colonel Mohammod Alom |
+-------+----+----------------------------------+
```

But I want the 4th index as 1st index. How to achieve this?

Comment: Try `WHEN name LIKE '%colonel%' AND name LIKE '%alom%' THEN 2`. Also, you are aware of full-text search?  Beware of SQL Injection!

Comment: `ORDER BY (name LIKE 'colonel alom') + (name LIKE 'colonel') + (name LIKE 'alom') DESC`

Comment: `LIKE` without wildcard(s) `%`?

Comment: @Akina, didn't you answer and I close a duplicate of this question last week?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46421200/2943403, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18725941/2943403, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1016804/2943403

Comment: @Akina this method not working but idk why!

Comment: @mickmackusa the question you pointed is hard to find via search. I searched a lot but this question didn't show up in front of me!